# XSLT with in CQWP leaving html tags open when empty

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt

We have some XSLT when the value of Message is NULL the h2 transforms into a self closing tag. How can we stop this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/> 
    <xsl:template match="/">   <xsl:for-each select="Title"><h2><xsl:value-of select="Message"/> </h2>  </xsl:for-each>  </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the message in a choose block?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Title">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(Message) &gt; 0">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="Message"/> </h2>
    </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
         //something to handle null or empty messages
      </xsl:otherwise> 
  </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that way would be rather verbose as I need to do it in a number of places. If I was going to do it with a test I would use this code <xsl:if test="Message != ''"> <h2><xsl:value-of select="Message"/> </h2></xsl:if>

Comment: If you need to do it in a number of places, you could always make it a template and just call that template where needed.  I went with choose so you could inject anything you wanted into the output like a generic message or any other html.